# Avoid Scrolling for Absolutely Positioned Element

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have an absolutely positioned element that I want to extend just outside the main content width.  The element is supposed to be a semi transparent watermark that overlaps with the main content area.

The problem is that the page scrolls if the watermark gets cut off.  I'd rather it just get cut off if it doesn't fit in the page, and not extend for the sake of the watermark.

Here's a demo:
https://tinker.io/661ec/2

Comment: Change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed;` : https://tinker.io/661ec/3

Comment: @Andy thanks, but position fixed doesn't work because I need it to be connected to the page content, and not the browser viewport.  I've come up with a solution that I think works pretty well: https://tinker.io/661ec/5

Answer (score 0):

The overflow attribute tells the page what to do when the page is too big to fit. If you apply the option
{overflow: hidden;}
where you want it to show, (ie, in a div or for the entire page, or just on an image), then the page won't scroll. However, you effectively lose the information for the overflow while it remains overflow, so it's a trade-off.